# Redefining types in Julia: invalid redefinition of constant

Tags: oop, types, julia

Lets say I assign a type `Person` in Julia:

```
type Person
    name::String
    male::Bool
    age::Float64
    children::Int
end

function describe(p::Person)
    println("Name: ", p.name, " Male: ", p.male)
    println("Age: ", p.age, " Children: ", p.children)
end


ted = Person("Ted",1,55,0)

describe(ted)
```

Which will output with the function:

```
Name: Ted Male: true
Age: 55.0 Children: 0
```

Then I modify the features for type `Person` where I added a new category to the type `eyes`

```
type Person
    name::String
    male::Bool
    age::Float64
    children::Int
    eyes::String
end


ted = Person("Ted",1,55,0,brown)
```

If I run the function now I get an error

```
Error evaluating REPL:
invalid redefinition of constant Person
 in include_string at loading.jl:97
```

What is the best way to work around this when developing new code? other than making a module as suggested in the [julia FAQ](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#How-can-I-modify-the-declaration-of-a-type-in-my-session?)

Comment: Why don't you want to make a module? Is the [workspace()](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/base/#Base.workspace) function to clear the `Main` module more in line with what you are looking for?

Comment: @ToivoHenningsson Yes that is what I am looking for. You have to add it above your script. You can put it in the answer and I will check it off. Thanks!

Comment: This is especially frustrating for editing code in [JuliaBox](https://www.juliabox.org/), where rerunning a cell that defines a Type results in an error... :/

Comment: This seems to be in flux (e.g., see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/25207). Revise.jl (https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl) seems to be the current flavor of the day for handling this.

Comment: Fixing the julia compiler is actually the best answer to "What is the best way to work around this when developing new code?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [workspace()](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.workspace) function to clear the `Main` module if you don't want to put the code in its own module.

Comment: Is it possible to only undefine the one single definition for the type Person? So the declaration for Person could be `undefine Person` `type Person ... end`?

Comment: Sorry, no. But making a module for your test code is really quite a handy way to be able to reload it without clearing everything, I think that would be the best solution if you have eg removed the type.

Comment: Can you create separate modules inside a single `ipynb` file?

Comment: Modules aren't tied to files at all, so sure.

Comment: This has been removed in recent versions of Julia

Comment: workspace() function has been removed. Doesn't work for me on Julia v1.4.

Comment: @Peheje: Please can you rephrase to clarify what you mean by this: the OP problem, that modules will solve the problem, or something else