# Can Revise.jl handle `ERROR: LoadError: invalid redefinition of constant`?

Tags: error-handling, julia

I tried to work around the problem described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26876064/6151828) using [`Revise.jl`](https://timholy.github.io/Revise.jl/stable/). My initial code is (stored as `tmp_SE.jl`):

```
struct Person
    name::String
    male::Bool
    age::Float64
    children::Int
    # eyes::String
  end

function describe(p::Person)
    println("Name: ", p.name, "Male: ", p.male)
    println("Age: ", p.age, "Children: ", p.children)
end
```

I launch Julia REPL and perform the following sequence:

```
using Revise
include("tmp_SE.jl")
ted=Person("Ted", 1, 55, 0)
describe(ted)
```

which works correctly.

I then type

```
edit("tmp_SE.jl")
```

which opens the editor, in which I un-comment the last line in the structure. If I then try

```
include("tmp_SE.jl")
```

I get `ERROR: LoadError: invalid redefinition of constant Person`,
whereas trying straightforward

```
ted=Person("Ted", 1, 55, 0, "brown")
```

results in `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Person(::String, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::String)`

In other words, the behavior is the same, as if I were not using `Revise.jl`.

I would appreciate help on this issue. Perhaps, there is a step that I am missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is not supported.

The Revise [documentation](https://timholy.github.io/Revise.jl/stable/limitations/) reads:

> There are some kinds of changes that Revise (or often, Julia itself) cannot incorporate into a running Julia session:
>
> - changes to type definitions or consts
> - conflicts between variables and functions sharing the same name
> - removal of exports
>
> These kinds of changes require that you restart your Julia session.